# How to install DDEV on Docker on WSL 2?

Tags: software-installation, docker, windows-subsystem-for-linux, drupal

I wish to install a [Drupal web application](https://www.drupal.org/) **on DDEV on Docker on WSL 2** and I have found the following instructions overwhelming.

Is there a simpler way?

---

### [The instructions I have found](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/)

#### 1)

```bash
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io containerd runc
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ca-certificates curl gnupg lsb-release
```

#### 2)

```bash
curl -fsSL https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg | sudo gpg --dearmor -o /usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg
echo "deb [arch=$(dpkg --print-architecture) signed-by=/usr/share/keyrings/docker-archive-keyring.gpg] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu $(lsb_release -cs) stable" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/docker.list > /dev/null
```

#### 3)

```bash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io
sudo groupadd docker && sudo usermod -aG docker $USER
```

#### Post installation script

```bash
echo "wsl.exe -u root service docker status > /dev/null || wsl.exe -u root service docker start > /dev/null" >> ~/.bashrc
```

#### Windows side instructions

> You can then `source ~/.bashrc` to start immediately, or it should start the next time you open git-bash.
>
> - Install mkcert on the Windows side; this may be easiest with Chocolatey: In an administrative PowerShell,

```bash
Set-ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Scope Process -Force; [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol -bor 3072; iex ((New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString('https://chocolatey.org/install.ps1'))
```

> - In an administrative PowerShell: `choco install -y mkcert`
> - In an administrative PowerShell, `run mkcert -install` and answer the prompt allowing the installation of the Certificate Authority.
> - In an administrative PowerShell, run the command `setx CAROOT "$(mkcert -CAROOT)"; If ($Env:WSLENV -notlike "*CAROOT/up:*") { setx WSLENV "CAROOT/up:$Env:WSLENV" }`.
>
> This will set WSL2 to use the Certificate Authority installed on the Windows side. * Double-check in Ubuntu (or your distro): echo `$CAROOT` should show something like `/mnt/c/Users/<you>/AppData/Local/mkcert`
>
> - Inside your WSL2 distro, `mkcert -install`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a simpler way?

While I can make that one step easier for you, ultimately you are missing a *great deal* of the installation instructions, so unfortunately it's likely going to be a bit *more* complicated, sorry to say.

First, you mention wanting to install a Drupal application via DDEV.  Then you link to instructions for installing *Docker*, but that's just *part* of the installation process.

First, start with the [DDEV-local installation instructions for Windows/WSL2](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#windows-wsl2)

To summarize those high-level steps:

- Installing Chocolatey package manager (optional).
- One time initialization of mkcert.
- Installing WSL2 and installing a distro like Ubuntu.
- Installing or upgrading to the latest Docker Desktop for Windows with WSL2 enabled.
- Installing DDEV inside your distro.

The "detailed" instructions are right below that section, and they are currently 17 steps.  The page you linked to is really just the "Step 7" part of those.  Make sure you have completed the previous 6 steps first, including installing WSL.  Note that those instructions, which reference `wsl --install`, do require a recent version of Windows 10 or 11 (2021H2 or later).

However, we can at least make the Docker installation step that you linked to a bit easier.

The page you linked to mentions two different methods of installing Docker on Windows:

- [Windows Installation: Docker Desktop for Windows](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/#windows-installation-docker-desktop-for-windows) - Which links to a single installer.
- Or [Windows Installation: WSL2 with Docker (Linux) Installed Inside](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/docker_installation/#windows-installation-wsl2-with-docker-linux-installed-inside)

These instructions probably should be labeled as "Option 1" and "Option 2", or "Alternative installation", or something to make it more clear.

As the instructions say, the "traditional" (a.k.a. "simpler") method is to use Docker Desktop, which will set everything up for you.

Note that Docker Desktop does require a paid license *if* you are working in a business with more than 250 employees or more than $10m in annual revenue (current information, but future readers should check to see what the requirements are at the time of reading).  However, you've come across one of the reasons why, IMHO, it's well worth it -- It will ultimately save you more time/money than the cost of the license (if you require it).

After installing Docker itself (via Docker Desktop), proceed with the other steps of the installation.